# I want to display username of comment's owner, however, comments table has user_id only

Tags: php, laravel

After I send the variable that contains the comments to the view, I can only display the user id. This is why I need to somehow foreach through all the comments and based on their user_id to add a new key-pair value with username-username and send it to the view afterwards. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble figuring how to do that.

```
public function specificImage($id){
    $similarImages = null;
    $image = Image::with('comments.user')->find($id);
    $subImages = Image::where('parent_id', $id)->get();
    $views = $image->views;
    $image->views = $views + 1;
    $image->save();
    $authorId = $image->user_id;
    $author = User::find($authorId);
    $comments = Comment::where('image_id', $id)->get();
    $recentImages = Image::where('parent_id', NULL)->where('user_id', $authorId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();

    $tag = Tag::whereHas('images', function($q) use ($id) {
        return $q->where('taggable_id', $id);
    })->first();

    if (!empty($tag)) {
        $tagId = $tag->id;
    }

    if (!empty($tagId)) {
        $similarImages = Image::where('parent_id', NULL)->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tagId) {
            return $q->where('tag_id', $tagId);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
    }

    return view('specificImage', ['image' => $image,'subImages' => $subImages, 'recentImages' => $recentImages, 'similarImages' => $similarImages, 'author' => $author, 'comments' => $comments]);
}
```

Table:

```
Table: Comments
Columns: id, user_id, image_id, comment
```

Image model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function tags(){
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }

    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function updateVotes()
    {
        $this->upvotes = Vote::where('image_id', $this->id)->where('vote', true)->count();
        $this->downvotes = Vote::where('image_id', $this->id)->where('vote', false)->count();
        $this->save();
    }

    public function updateComments()
    {
        $this->comments = Comment::where('image_id', $this->id)->count();
        $this->save();
    }

}
```

Comment model:

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function image(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

User model:

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }

    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles) {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role){
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="specific-image-flexbox">

        <div class="specific-image-column">
            <div class='specific-image-container'>
                <img class='specific-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                @foreach($subImages as $subImage)
                    <img class='specific-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$subImage->file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="artwork-info-column">
            <div class="artwork-info-container">
                <p class='title'>{{ $image->name }}<p>
                <p class='author'>на<a href='{{url("profile/".$author->username )}}'><span class='usernameA artwork-info-username-span'>{{$author->username}}</span></a><img class='artwork-info-profile-picture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$author->profile_picture)}}'></p>
                @if(Auth::user())
                    @if(Auth::id() === $image->user_id || Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
                        <a class='placeholderDelete' href='{{ route('deleteImage', ['image_id' => $image->id]) }}'><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Изтрий изображението</a>
                    @endif
                @endif
                <p class='description'>{{ $image->description }}</p>
                <p class='description'>Техника: {{ $image->medium }}</p>
                <p><i class="far fa-eye"></i> {{ $image->views }} Преглеждания</p>
                <p><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{ $image->upvotes }} Харесвания</p>
                <p class='commentsCount'><i class="far fa-comments"></i> {{ $image->comments }} Коментари</p>
                <a class='downloadImage' href="{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->file_name)}}" download="{{ $image->name }}"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i> Изтегли</a>
                <!--<a class='placeholderDelete fas fa-expand' href='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->file_name)}}'></a>-->

                <div class='social-container'>
                    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"
                        data-url="{{ url()->full() }}"
                        data-title="{{ $image->name }} by {{ $author->username }}"
                        data-description="{{ $image->description }}"
                        data-media="{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->file_name)}}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                @if(!empty($recentImages))
                    @if(count($recentImages) >= 9)
                    <p class='author'>Още произведения на<a href='{{url("profile/".$author->username )}}'><span class='usernameA artwork-info-username-span'>{{$author->username}}</span></a><img class='artwork-info-profile-picture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$author->profile_picture)}}'></p>
                    <div class="more-images-container">
                        @foreach($recentImages as $recentImage)
                            <div class="more-images-container-element">
                                <a href='{{url("image/".$recentImage->id)}}'>
                                    <img class='more-images' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/miniImages/".$recentImage->file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    @endif
                @endif

                @if(!empty($similarImages))
                    @if(count($similarImages) >= 9)
                    <p class='similar-images'>Подобни произведения</p>
                    <div class="similar-images-container">
                        @foreach($similarImages as $similarImage)
                            <div class="similar-images-container-element">
                                <a href='{{url("image/".$similarImage->id)}}'>
                                    <img class='more-images' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/miniImages/".$similarImage->file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    @endif
                @endif

                @auth
                    <div class='postComments'>
                        <form method='POST' action=''>
                            <textarea class='comment-section' name='comment'></textarea>
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="{{ $image->id }}">
                            <button class='postComment submit' type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Изпрати</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                @endauth

                <div class='comments'>
                    @foreach($image->comments as $comment)
                        {{ $comment->user->username }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var urlComment = '{{ route('comment') }}';
    var urlLike = '{{ route('vote') }}';
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Do you have relationships set up the models i.e. a comments relationship in `Image` and a user relationship in `Comment`?

Comment: I've added my models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `user` relationship to your `Comment` model as well:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

You can then [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships and then access them in your blade file:

```
public function specificImage($id)
{
    $image = Image::with('comments.user')->find($id);

    return view('specificImage', ['image' => $image]);
}
```

Then in your blade file you would have something like:

```
@foreach($image->comments as $comment)

    {{ $comment->user->username }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a ""Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\Art Showcase\resources\views\specificImage.blade.php)"" error when trying this

Comment: @Bobimaru What version of Laravel are you using? Have you added all the code for your `Image` and `Comment` model to your question?

Comment: Yes, I added the relations to my models. {{ App::VERSION() }} shows that I'm using 5.5.41

Comment: @Bobimaru So you don't have any other methods in your models?

Comment: Oh, I do but I removed those that are not related for better legibility. I'll update my post with all methods ( if for some reason a irrelevant method is causing this problem )

Comment: I've added my current live models with the changes

Comment: In that case I'm really not sure why it would be throwing that Exception with the code I've provided in my answer. Even if you don't have any comments attached to the Image the relationship should return an Collection which wouldn't cause there to be an issue with the foreach. Can you add the blade to your question as well please as it might be something else that's causing the issue.

Comment: Hmmm for some reason I see your replies with huge delay. Anyway I've update the code but it's literally the same as what you wrote.

Comment: @Bobimaru Is that your entire blade file?

Comment: Oh no, I uploaded the whole thing.

Comment: @Bobimaru Are you definite passing `$subImages`, `$recentImages` and `$similarImages` from your controller? If so, if you remove the `$image->comments` foreach loop does it get rid of the error?

Comment: By removing the foreach, the error goes away. I am passing $subImages, $recentImages and $similarImages from my controller. I've updated my code where I pass the variables so you can see them.

Comment: @Bobimaru The only thing I can suggest is changing ` $image = Image::with('comments.user')->find($id);` to ` $image = Image::with('comments.user')->findOrFail($id);` If the page still works then I don't know what else I can suggest.

Comment: Sadly that didn't do anything :|